# UWP List view rendering issue

Tags: listview, scroll, uwp, windows-10, rendering

After update SDK to the 10.0.15063 version I have faced with the following problem: when a list view is being scrolled quickly it does not manage to render all items in time
Here is a link to video where the problem is shown:
[***Link***](https://youtu.be/6Q2n5IuYqsM)

Does somebody have any ideas how the issue could be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior caused due to ListView Virtualization. Due to this all items are not rendered at once which greatly improves performance.
Thus the items in the "*Unrealized*" zone get rendered when they are in the "*realization window*"

Please refer to the image below for better understanding : [More info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alainza/2014/09/03/listview-basics-and-virtualization-concepts/)

[image: ListView Virtualization]

Comment: You cannot disable the default UI virtualization of the ListView but you can place your listview inside a scrollviewer. This will ensure the ListView scrolling is disabled while the scrollViewer will scroll the content. This is a workaround and may behave abruptly.. you can use it if your listview does not have too many items,else you will have serious memory and performance issues ..

Comment: You really do NOT want to disable this. You can improve the visual performance however by disabling ScrollingPlaceholders on the listview, and ensuring you're using x:Binding and optimised text rendering.

(FYI, changing the ListView's ItemsPanel will disable virtualizing), however again, for performance and memory reasons leaving it on is usually vastly preferred despite the rendering artifacts (which should show you how expensive all these items are to render in the first place... and why they're virtualized)